# the usage of int pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

When I debug my OS, I made the following change to kill a bug:

```
struct proc {
    int p_status;
};
int *status;   
struct proc *childP;
```

Before:

```
*status = childP->p_status;
```

I changed it to:

```
status = &childP->p_status;
```

Then the OS works fine. But from my understanding, shouldn't the before and the later work the same? What's the difference between them? Thank you!

Comment: To give you a hint: what is the difference between changing the address on an envelope so the letter goes to a different house, and sending a different letter to the same address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*status = childP->p_status;`
means: assign the memory location which `status` points to with `childP->p_status` value

`status = &childP->p_status;`
means: set `status` to point to memory location of `childP->p_status`

Answer (score 0):

The `*` and `&` operators are somewhat overloaded and it's an easy mistake to make.

```
typename * variable
//e.g.
int * status;
```

declares a variable of type int -- operator `*` in this case is binding to the typename and becoming a modifier.

```
* variable
```

means `the contents of the address pointed to by variable`

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    char text[] = "hello, world!";
    char* p = text; // declare 'p' as a 'char*' and point it to 'h'
    *p = 'H'; // change the first letter of text to a capital
    std::cout << text << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/mmi9UH

There are various ways you can write these statements, some programmers prefer to put the `*` on the left side when declaring variables to make this distinct

```
int* status;
int * status;
int *status;
```

all declare the same variable. However, it gets cloudy using the first form when you have to declare multiple variables

```
int* p1, p2;
```

declares a pointer p1 but *p2 is just an int*

```
int * p1, * p2;
int *p1, *p2;
```

declare two pointers. Lefty-pointer-types tend to do

```
int* p1;
int* p2;
```

Comment: @lkkeepmoving haha - yes :)

Comment: Fixed the ideone demo too.

Answer (score 0):

if `status` doesn't point to allocated memory before `*status = childP->p_status;` then you have a bug. as the status pointer will point to an unknown memory address.

The second option means the status points to the same address the the struct member. This pointer acts like an alias - a shorter version of `&childP->p_status`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to access a value before it has been created.  When you're trying the ChildP->p_status segment is called, you haven't really loaded a value into p_status yet, so the result is an error.

The second one, where you're loading status with an address value instead, gives struct a concrete value to deal with - and is, in my opinion, a better way to do it.  It's always better to set the value of the pointer itself first rather than the pointer value.